# phantomjs not working using exec

Tags: php, server, phantomjs, har

i can run phantomjs-netsniff code to create har file in terminal (as root) but when i execute it using php it returns does create har file but with zero bites. same code executed both times.

i have disabled safe-mode in php, 777 permission on har generating folder. what i have missed.

my OS is centos 64 bit. and i used https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 to install.

php code

```
<?php

$rrd= 'phantomjs /var/www/xxx/netsniff.js "http://www.wiki.com" > /var/www/xxx/xx/xx.har';
exec($rrd);

?>
```

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: Try checking for errors.  `$output = array(); $returnCode = null; exec($rrd, $output, $returnCode); print_r($output); echo "Return code was $returnCode\n";`  See what comes up.

Comment: you totally saved me bro. it gave me error 127 and i corrected it. but this is strange. this code is already running on another server. why would it throw error on this server (both identical)? . can you give that as answer instead of comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always check for errors; this can tell you what is going wrong:

```
$output = array();
$returnCode = null;
exec($rrd, $output, $returnCode);
print_r($output);
echo "Return code was $returnCode\n";
```

From your comment, you say you get return code 127, which usually means "command not found".  Is `phantomjs` on your path?  If you type `which phantomjs` as the user that PHP is running as, what do you get?  An easy way to avoid this is to just specify the full path to the binary in the command, i.e., use `/path/to/phantomjs` instead of just `phantomjs` in the command string.

Comment: Need to include any phantomjs file before your code